# Delete a Object from an Array of Objects

Tags: java

Is there a way to do this:

```
Player[] player = new Player[numOfPlayers];
for(int i=0; i < numOfPlayers; i++){
    player[i] =  new Player("Player"+i, 0); 
}
//becomes like this right? 
player[0].name='a';
player[1].name='b'
player[2].name='c'
player[3].name='t'
player[i].name='baz'
```

How can I remove say `player[2]` so that the new array of objects becomes:

```
player[0].name='a';
player[1].name='c'
player[2].name='t'
player[i].name='baz'
```

Comment: You should consider using `List<Player>` instead of `Player[]`.

Comment: @YoungHobbit However you are right, do note that under a List an array like this is used which is resized at times

Comment: @engineercoding Yeah. You are correct. It is about the abstraction provided by List interface. So the programmer need to worry and less possibility of errors.